# Using a javascript function on inputted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two boxes, the first is the input and the other the output. I want the output box to display the text inputted in the input box, as converted by the javascript function.

I hope that makes sense! For example I have a function to change the letters of inputted text, but don't know how to use it to take what has been inputted and display it in the second box.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Any errors? What result do you expect ?

Comment: you need to learn about jquery selector and jquery events first. just google these terms and you will see lots of information.

Comment: @Deep okay, I probably should study up more on jQuery first, kind of just went into this blindly

Comment: Do you want to [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/oww74gje/)?

Comment: @Mohammad, not exactly, I want to input text and have it return an encrypted string. I already have the javascript function written, I just need to implement it somehow

Comment: Write your custom function instead of my function to do this work.

Comment: I put my function beneath yours, not sure how to use it and have it work...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but you can get input value like this: `$('#input').val();`

Then change it as you need and assign value to your output element like this `$('#output').val(yourChangedValue);`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this :)

Comment: Hi @l-emi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.